# Customise "add to cart" button

Tags: addtocart

I want to edit the standard "add to cart" button to a "CLICK TO BUY" button.

So that, once clicked will link through to the same product on another store (same magento install).

> Store 1 is a trade only site with no purchase function but would like
>   to edit as above to link through to store 2 for an option to buy.

I think its relatevly simple. Some sort of get statement that looks up the URL and then changes the web address from `www.store1.com` to `www.store2.com`

Any advice would be much appreciated.